# Entity Framework ObjectContext.SaveChanges fails on unique key column update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, unique-key

Consider very simple database table:

```
CREATE TABLE UkTest(
  id int NOT NULL,
  uk int NOT NULL
)
Primary Key on id
Unique Key on uk
```

Then add 2 rows:

```
INSERT INTO UkTest (id,uk) VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO UkTest (id,uk) VALUES(2,2);
```

Then do 2 tests.

OK:

```
var db =  new Database1Entities();
var element1 = db.UkTest.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == 1);
var element2 = db.UkTest.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == 2);

element1.uk = 0;
element2.uk = 1;  // overrides previous element1.uk value
var count = db.SaveChanges();
```

Fails (before test revert uk values to 1 and 2!):

```
var db =  new Database1Entities();
var element1 = db.UkTest.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == 1);
var element2 = db.UkTest.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == 2);

element2.uk = 0;
element1.uk = 2;  // overrides previous element2.uk value
var count = db.SaveChanges();
// Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UkTest' with unique index 'UK_UkTest'
```

See that `ObjectContext.SaveChanges()` checks rows in the order of primary index.

Is there any way to force own order?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you call `SaveChanges()` twice, no, there is no way to control the order of SQL statements Entity Framework will send to the database. You could wrap the multiple `SaveChanges()` calls into an outer transaction to ensure still a transactional behaviour for the whole operation:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var db = new Database1Entities())
    {
        var element1 = db.UkTest.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == 1);
        var element2 = db.UkTest.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == 2);

        element2.uk = 0;
        db.SaveChanges();

        element1.uk = 2;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, a lot. Unfortunately my example was simplified. I'll try to post more difficult one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Slauma. I've found the solution. The key is to keep elements in several ObjectContext instances.

```
public class SavingElementsWithTransactionInOwnOrder
{
    public void SaveElements ()
    {
        var db = new Database1Entities();
        var element1 = db.UkTest.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == 1);
        element1.db = db;

        db = new Database1Entities();
        var element2 = db.UkTest.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == 2);
        element2.db = db;

        element2.uk = 0;
        element1.uk = 2;

        var scope = new TransactionScope();
        try{
            element2.db.SaveChanges();
            element1.db.SaveChanges();
            scope.Complete();
        }
        finally{
            scope.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public partial class UkTest
{
    public Database1Entities db { get; set; }
}
```